# Is it possible to add Microsoft Graph delegated permissions to Azure AD app via Powershell?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I registered an application in Azure AD from PowerShell using the below script.

```js
//To create new application
$myapp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName  MyApp 
$myappId=$myapp.AppId

//To set ApplicationID URI
Set-AzureADApplication -ApplicationId $myappId -IdentifierUris "api://$myappId"


//To retrieve details of new application
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq $myapp"
```

Now I want to set delegated API permissions(Calendars.Read, Application.Read.All, Directory.Read.All) for this app.

From Azure Portal, I know how to assign these. But is it possible to add these permissions via PowerShell? If yes, can anyone help me with the script or cmdlets?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set delegated API permissions via ***PowerShell***

Initially, please note **AppID** of new application that can be retrieved by below cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq $myapp"
```

Check whether you have Service Principal named "**Microsoft Graph**" using below cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }
```

In order to assign API permissions via PowerShell, you should know the **GUIDs** of those delegated permissions that can be displayed using below cmdlet:

```
$MSGraph.Oauth2Permissions | FT ID, Value
```

Note the IDs of required permissions like Calendars.Read, Application.Read.All and Directory.Read.All

***Please find the complete script below:***

```
$myapp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName  MyApp 
$myappId=$myapp.ObjectId
 
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'MyApp'"
$MSGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }
$MSGraph.Oauth2Permissions | FT ID, Value

# Create a Resource Access resource object and assign the service principal’s App ID to it.
$Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$Graph.ResourceAppId = $MSGraph.AppId

# Create a set of delegated permissions using noted IDs
$Per1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "c79f8feb-a9db-4090-85f9-90d820caa0eb","Scope"

$Per2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "465a38f9-76ea-45b9-9f34-9e8b0d4b0b42","Scope"

$Per3 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "06da0dbc-49e2-44d2-8312-53f166ab848a","Scope"

$Graph.ResourceAccess = $Per1, $Per2, $Per3

# Set the above resource access object to your application ObjectId so permissions can be assigned.
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $myappId -RequiredResourceAccess $Graph
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to assign Permissions to Azure AD App by using PowerShell?](https://rajanieshkaushikk.com/2019/07/31/how-to-assign-permissions-to-azure-ad-app-by-using-powershell/)